# Probability of string misidentified in Bloom filter

Tags: probability

I'm attempting a question related to Bloom filters:

> Our Bloom filter uses $3$ different independent hash functions $H_1, H_2, H_3$ that each take any string as input and each return an index into a bit-array of length $n$. Each index is equally likely for each hash function.
>
> To add a string into the set, feed it to each of the $3$ hash functions to get $3$ array positions. Set the bits at all these positions to $1$. For example, initially all values in the bit-array are zero. In this example $n = 10$:
>
> ```
> Index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> Value: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```
>
> After adding the string "word", where $H_1($"word"$)=4$, $H_2($"word"$)=7$ and $H_3($"word"$)=8$:
>
> ```
> Index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> Value: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
> ```
>
> Bits are never switched back to $0$. Consider a Bloom filter with $n=9000$ buckets. You have added $m=1000$ strings to the filter.
>
> a) What is the probability that the first bucket has $0$ strings hashed to it?
>
> b) To check whether a string is in the set, feed it to each of the $3$ hash functions to get $3$ array positions. If any of the bits at these positions is $0$, the element is not in the set. If all bits at these positions are $1$, the string *may* be in the set; but it could be that those bits are $1$ because some of the other strings hashed to the same values. You may assume that the value of one bucket is independent of the value of all others.
>
> What is the probability that a string which has not previously been added to the set will be misidentified as in the set. That is, what is the probability that the bits at all of its hash positions are already $1$?

For the first part, probability that a certain string is not hashed by $H_1$ to first bucket is $\frac{8999}{9000}$. Probability that that string isn't hashed by any of the $3$ functions is therefore $\big(\frac{8999}{9000}\big)^3$. Probability that none of the strings is hashed by any of the hashing functions to the first bucket is then $\big(\frac{8999}{9000}\big)^{3000}$.

For the second part, we're supposed to find the probability that $3$ specific buckets (say buckets no. $p,q,r$) already have a string hashed to them. This is

$$P(p=1,q=1,r=1)=1-P((p=0)\cup(q=0)\cup(r=0))$$

The union can be calculated as (denoting events $p=0, q=0, r=0$ as $p_0, q_0, r_0$ respectively)

$$P(p_0\cup q_0\cup r_0)=\\P(p_0)+P(q_0)+P(r_0)-P(p_0,q_0)-P(q_0,r_0)-P(r_0,p_0)+P(p_0,q_0,r_0)$$

$P(p_0),P(q_0),P(r_0)$ will be the same as the answer to the first question. $P(p_0,q_0)$ will be (using similar logic as in part a) $\big(\frac{8998}{9000}\big)^{3000}$. $P(p_0,q_0,r_0)$ will be $\big(\frac{8997}{9000}\big)^{3000}$. Plugging all these values in, we get the answer.

I'm not too sure about either part though. Are the answers right and the above approach correct? Is there a more efficient/better/alternate way to solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are correct, congratulations on your line of thought and especially on answer **b)**. But since it looks like you are not so confident of your answer, I will try to write it more rigorously and step by step to show why you are correct. I will assume you are familiar with the concept of independence.

A hash function is a function $H$ that receives a string $S$ and returns an index $H(S)$ in $\{0,\ldots,8999\}$ with uniform distribution. He said that you receive m = 1000 strings, so let's denote them by $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{1000}$. **We will also assume that the strings are also independent**. This is an important assumption that the exercise did not state, but I think it's implicity. Let's tackle the questions.

**a)** The first bucket has a $0$ value in it if, for every string, for every hash function, the hash index of that string is different than 0. In terms of probability (much like you did in letter **b**), we write

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\overset{m}{\underset{i = 1}{\cap}} \{ H_1(S_i) \neq 0, H_2(S_i) \neq 0, H_3(S_i) \neq 0 \} \right) \quad.$$

Now the notation might be heavy, but notice it just translates our thought to a symbol: $\overset{m}{\underset{i = 1}{\cap}}$ denotes intersection, and it's saying that we are considering that the event
 $$\{ H_1(S_i) \neq 0, H_2(S_i) \neq 0, H_3(S_i) \neq 0 \}$$ 
happens for each strings. The event clearly denotes that the three hash indexes are different than $0$ for string $S_i$. We proceed to compute the probability

\begin{array}{l}
\mathbb{P}\left(\overset{m}{\underset{i = 1}{\cap}} \{ H_1(S_i) \neq 0, H_2(S_i) \neq 0, H_3(S_i) \neq 0 \} \right) \overset{\scriptsize\mbox{string indep.}}{=} \\
 \prod_{i=1}^{1000}\left[\mathbb{P}(\{ H_1(S_i) \neq 0, H_2(S_i) \neq 0, H_3(S_i) \neq 0 \})\right] \overset{\scriptsize\mbox{hash indep.}}{=} \\
\prod_{i=1}^{1000}\left[\mathbb{P}( H_1(S_i) \neq 0)\times\mathbb{P}( H_2(S_i) \neq 0)\times\mathbb{P}( H_3(S_i) \neq 0)\right] = \\
\prod_{i=1}^{1000}\left[\left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)\times \left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right) \times \left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)\right] =\\
\left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)^{3000}\quad.
\end{array}

This is exactly what you did logically by multiplying the probabilities of the hash index being different from zero $3\times m$ times.

**b)** This one is very interesting! The exercise actually allows you to do it in a much simples way: **"You may assume that the value of one bucket is independent of the value of all others."** The exercise calculates an **approximation**, your solution gives the **exact** result, but it's harder to come by.

By using the hypothesis of the exercise, the probability you wrote breaks down to

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(p=1,q=1,r=1) &\overset{\scriptsize\mbox{exerc. hyp}}{=} \mathbb{P}(p=1)\times\mathbb{P}(q=1)\times\mathbb{P}(r=1) =\\
 &= (1-\mathbb{P}(p=0))\times(1-\mathbb{P}(q=0))\times(1-\mathbb{P}(r=0)) \overset{\scriptsize\mbox{from a) }}{=}\\
 &= \left( 1 - \left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)^{3000} \right)\times \left( 1 - \left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)^{3000} \right) \times \left( 1 - \left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)^{3000} \right)\\
&= \left( 1 - \left(\frac{8999}{9000}\right)^{3000} \right)^3\quad.
\end{align*}

As for your solution, you wrote and calculated the probabilities correctly. You prove each one of them just like in **a)**. I won't do it here because the answer would be pretty long. However, I recommend you trying to calculate at least for one of them (say $\mathbb{P}(p_0,q_0)$) so you become more confident with the rigorous reasoning.

The approximate answer, the one the exercise suggests, gives a probability of $2.278118\%$, while your answer, which is the exact value, gives a probability of $2.276501\%$. You can see they are pretty close!

**Obs:** It was very fun to read about Bloom filter's, thanks for bringing the subject.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! I think there's still an issue with my answer to b). I've assumed that $p,q,r$ are distinct; but two or more of them could be the same. I can modify my solution to include case 1: all buckets for the new string are different, case 2: two of the buckets are same and case 3: all buckets are the same, and multiply the answer for each case by the probability of buckets being selected in that way (e.g. multiply answer for case 2 by the probability of selecting buckets s.t. two are the same). And then add all up. Of course, that seems like a massive pain for a single problem.

Comment: Indeed we supposed they are different, but we can solve the other cases just like above. However, you should not add them up directly. You should either assume which case you are working on or put a prior distribution to the cases, and then add the probabilities multiplied by their priors.